# Getting started developing for iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hey all, quick question.  My end goal is to start developing apps for the iPhone but my current skillset is pretty limited.  I'm wondering how far back I should go back and where I should start as far as becoming familiar with coding before the iPhone SDK course on Lynda.com isn't something that makes my eyes glaze over.

My experience: I taught myself html from the html for dummies book maybe 10 years ago, I've taken a dreamweaver class and built a few sites with it, and I've customized a self hosted Wordpress blog by playing with the php code.

Any tips on where I should start if I want to head down the road toward developing for the iPhone?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the iphone is what you want to do then I would recommend starting with the iPhone SDK and some samples. Deving native apps iPhone is pretty different than HTML - it is mostly Objective C where you have to worry about memory allocation/cleanup and pointers, but the quickest way to find if you like it or not is to download the free SDK and try it out.

If you find you don't like it, the browser capabilities on both iPhone and iPad are pretty advanced and I have seen some very good browser based apps built using web technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I put together this list of resources for learning iOS Development:

http://bkbeachlabs.com/blog/ios-programming-resources-for-learning-ios-development/

Hope that helps!